# Extension of abstract types in different modules

Tags: oop, fortran, abstract-type

In the following piece of code, an abstract type with a private variables (name) and an access function to this variable, which is supposed to be defined by all derived types, is defined in a module:

```
module baseTypeModule

type, abstract :: baseType
private
    character(len=maxLengthCompLabel) :: Name = ""           ! Component name
contains
    procedure, non_overridable :: getName                    ! Access functio to Name (read only)
end type baseType

contains

character(len=100) function getName(this)
    implicit none
    class(baseType), intent(in) :: this
    getName = this % Name
end function getName

end module baseTypeModule
```

As there are many other variables and functions in each derived type, I would like to define each derived types in a different module.

Is there a way in Fortran to tell the compiler that I want that only derived types of baseType would be able to change the variable Name?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Accessibility of component names uses the same "by module" model as for other module entities.  If the other derived types are in different modules, then they cannot access the `Name` component.

Bear in mind that derived types don't actually contain procedures - they contain bindings for procedures.  Consequently a derived type can't really "do" anything.  Also a single procedure could be bound to multiple types.